# Maze Javascript Problem involving recursive functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

#### Problem:

A maze is represented by the `maze` variable. A character can start on one of the top four cells and then go down to one of the 3 cells beneath that are close to him. Find all the possible paths programmatically.

#### Expected Output :

For each possible path log to the console an array with all the cell's column it will cross.
example : [3, 2, 2, 1]

#### My solution :

For some reason it won't work, need help.

```js
const m = 4;

const maze = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
  [13, 14, 15, 16]
]

const getPaths = (previousCols, row, col) => {
  previousCols.push(col)

  if (row < m) {
    getPaths(previousCols, row + 1, col);

    if (col > 0) {
      getPaths(previousCols, row + 1, col - 1);
    }

    if (col < m) {
      getPaths(previousCols, row + 1, col + 1);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(previousCols)
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
  getPaths([], 0, i)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be `for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {`?

Comment: yes, you're right, my bad. but still it doesn't seem to return all paths.

Comment: What does the `m` variable signify?

Comment: the width and the height of the maze.

Comment: Can you tell us how it is not working?  What answer are you getting and what are you expecting?

Comment: @KyloTheDev don't use vaguely named variable and please add expected output.

Comment: My bad, sorry for the confusion, first time on stackoverflow, I expect it to log to the console for each possible path, an array with all the cell's columns it will cross. I'll edit and put and example on the post right now.